# Cannot open lightning component from URL button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom-button, urlhacking, custom-url

I have to open a lightning component from a button on related list. Hence I created a list button in child object and added it on the page layout of parent object.

I created a list button with URL as below

```
/lightning/cmp/c__Commercial_Opportunity_Product?c__firstName="Nilang"
```

Commercial_Opportunity_Product is the name of my lightning component. I have passed firstName as parameter. Below is the code of Commercial_Opportunity_Product component.

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,lightning:isUrlAddressable,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="parentId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"/>
<div class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
    <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
            <div>
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h2 class="slds-modal__title">New Commercial Opportunity Product</h2>
                    <p> Hello {!v.firstName}</p>
                </header>
                <div class="slds-p-vertical_small slds-text-body_medium">
                    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="form"
                                              recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                              objectApiName="GEFUE_Commercial_Opportunity_Product__c"     
                                              class="slds-card__body_inner">
                        <h2 class="slds-section-title--divider">Information</h2>
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                            <lightning:messages/>
                            <div class="slds-col ">
                                <lightning:inputField fieldName="GEFUE_Terminal__c" aura:id="terminalLookupId"/>
                                <lightning:inputField fieldName="GEFUE_Product__c" aura:id="productLookupId"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col">
                                <lightning:inputField fieldName="GEFUE_Opportunity__c" aura:id="oppLookupId"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </lightning:recordEditForm>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is code of its controller

```
({
    onPageReferenceChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var myPageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");
        var firstname = myPageRef.state.c__firstName;
        component.set("v.firstName", firstname);
    }
})
```

But when opening this component via the URL button in related list, it is taking me to another page and giving below error.

> This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app.

Below is the screenshot

[image]

Am I missing something here? I have also implemented lightining:isUrlAddressable for launching lightning component via a URL.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing page Reference in controller , refer this link :

[Navigation Example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/290868/please-help-me-with-the-navigation-component)   [component link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/CXmWcYSML/22/edit) to generate the URL to navigate to the lightning web component via the related list:-

[image]

In your case, using lightning:navigation will not work as you have to invoke it through a related list button which does not support Lightning Component button.

> Note:- This is not a documented way to do, but works.

Comment: What if firstName is dynamic? Or How to pass parameters as well in the URL?